# Countdown Jquery update DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I'm doing a vote system to a website i'm making where i need to make a count down but it need to have some functionability, i'm not realy good with jquery.

So this is my database:

```
Table: Votes

Rows: min_users, active
```

Let's say that i want a minimum of 100 users to vote in this poll, when it reaches 100 users it will start a countdown of lets say 7 days, when the countdown ends it will update the database and set active to 0.

I've seen some Jquery examples of updating a database, but i'm not realy sure whats the currect way to do what i want it to work.

I'm also making this with Laravel 5.

Comment: You can't update the database directly with jQuery. What you can do is make an ajax call to a PHP file on the server and that PHP file will do the heavy lifting and return a response via ajax.

Comment: I dont want it accessible to the public.. is there a better way? =/ is this possible to do a countdown by php?